# Cannot set a hidden form field using JavaScript nor with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a Form that uses JavaScript to get the browser/client Time Zone Offset value, I then need to set that value to a Form field so that when the Form is POSTED, it will send to my backend script.

I can `alert(clientTimeOffset)` with my code below and it alerts the correct value, however when I submit a form, it never set the hidden form field with that value so it never gets posted.

Below is all the code I have tried so far, any help please?

**Version 1**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

    // Set TimeZone Offset Form Value
    var d = new Date();
    var clientTimeOffset = (d.getTimezoneOffset()/ 60 *(-1))+5;
    jQuery("#timezone").val(clientTimeOffset);

});
```

**Version 2**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

    // Set TimeZone Offset Form Value
    var d = new Date();
    var clientTimeOffset = (d.getTimezoneOffset()/ 60 *(-1))+5;
    var x = document.getElementById("timezone");
    x.value=clientTimeOffset;

});
```

My Form Field...

```
<input type="hidden" name="timezone" id="timezone" />
```

Comment: Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Provided you don't have other elements with the same `id`, nothing else overwrites the value later, and that hidden field is actually in the form you're posting (as opposed to in some *other* form, or not in a form at all), that should be working.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder funny you mention that, that is exactly what the problem was, it's a huge form and somehow it ended up with 2 fields with the same ID, so the 2nd one would overwrite the first, thanks for pointing it out....This probably killed an hour of time

Answer (score 0):

I feel silly but the problem was, somehow I had 2 hidden form fields with the same #ID, so it would set the first value and then the second one would overwrite it as empty when the POST was made.  Maybe this will help someone someday, make sure you only have 1 form field that the selector matches!